# Bulk action button missing in list view Suite CRM

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am using Suite CRM 7.5.3, In the list view, 'Bulk action' button is missing. After i kept 'select all', only the delete button is appearing. i need 'Mass Update' option in the select box field. Is there any option we have to enable from the admin panel to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.